# How to delete the first row from the list in a column in power query?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a table with a column called custom:
[image]

I would like to delete the first row of every list in the column:
[image]

Is there anyway to do this?

The code is as below:

```
let  
StDt = [start],

AllDates = 
{Number.From([start])..Number.From([end])},

StoMonthDates = 
List.Distinct(
    List.Select(
        List.InsertRange(
            List.Transform(
                AllDates,
                each Date.StartOfDay(Date.From(_))
            ),
            0,
            {[start]}
        ),
        each Number.From(_) >= Number.From(StDt)
    )
)

in StoMonthDates
```

Comment: Are you looking for [**List.Skip()**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-skip)?

Comment: What does your data look like? In your screenshot, the first two rows differ only in format. That seems odd. Why do you need to remove the first item?

Comment: As they are replicated

Comment: Yes, that's why I wanted more information. If all you want to do is generate a list of the dates from `start` to `end` inclusive, just use the `List.Dates` function: `List.Dates(Date.From([start]),Duration.Days(Date.From([end]) - Date.From([start]))+1,#duration(1,0,0,0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of using `List.Dates` to create an inclusive list of the distinct dates from `start` to `end`

```
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each 
        List.Dates(Date.From([start]),
                    Duration.Days(Date.From([end]) - Date.From([start]))+1,
                    #duration(1,0,0,0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the `List.RemoveFirstN` function to remove the first row of every elements in the lists.

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each let  
StDt = [start],

AllDates = 
{Number.From([start])..Number.From([end])},

StoMonthDates = 
List.RemoveFirstN(
List.Distinct(
    List.Select(
        List.InsertRange(
            List.Transform(
                AllDates,
                each Date.StartOfDay(Date.From(_))
            ),
            0,
            {[start]}
        ),
        each Number.From(_) >= Number.From(StDt)
    )
),
1)

in StoMonthDates)
```